# How to troubleshoot java.lang.NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, wso2, nosuchmethoderror

I know that a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` means that the version of a class used for compiling is different from the version used at runtime. Usually, when I see this issue, I start the app.server in `java -verbose` mode, which tells me the jar file from which a class is loaded. If that jar file is not the one I intended to use, I know I'm using an incorrect version of the jar file.

Another approach I use, is to use `javap` to look at the method signatures of the class in the jar file I am using at runtime, to confirm that the jar does indeed contain the class with a different method signature.

I am seeing this error now in Karaf, an OSGi container and none of the above approaches are helping. `java -verbose` shows me the jar, `javap` shows me the method signature and the method signature is the same as that in the error stacktrace. In other words, I can see that the class from the jar being used at runtime *does* have the same method signature that the jvm says it cannot find.

Here is the exact stack trace, if it helps:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/axiom/soap/SOAPModelBuilder;
at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:55)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:179)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:108)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:67)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:354)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub.AuthenticationAdminStub.login(AuthenticationAdminStub.java:659)
```

Are there any other approaches I can/should use? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where do you get this class from ? Do you get it from the Service ? Are you using maven or any dependency managment library ?

Comment: Hello John, eventually did you fix the issue and find the cause? I am face the same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

The Karaf commands `exports [ids]`, `imports [ids]` and `classes [ids]` can used in combination with `grep`  (each command has a `--help` option).

From the bundle throwing the error (with id N), `imports N | grep org.apache.axiom.om` will tell you which bundle it is actually importing that package from.

And approaching from the other side, `exports | grep org.apache.axiom.om` will list the bundles that export that package.

I'd expect you'll see more than one line from the exports and the import command will show incorrect version is being used.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use java -verbose:class to see where classes are loaded from, which might show that the problematic class is loaded from a different bundle that you expected.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had already indicated that I use that approach.